# TexStudio indents the line instead of inserting a tab when I press Tab

Tags: texstudio

Even though I have no characters selected, TeXstudio 2.8.4 appears to indent the whole line instead of inserting `\t` at the position my cursor is. This makes it a pain to, for instance, use tabs to align a table's columns.

How can I make the Tab key behave exactly as in typical text editor? (insert `\t` at the position of the text cursor, not at the beginning of the current line)

Comment: In my editor the TAB key does precisely nothing, so that I'm sure to not insert in my file any `\t`. I believe they're evil. `;-)`

Comment: The new version indeed binds TAB to “indent selection”. I get a `<tab>` with Alt-TAB.

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately, `Alt+Tab` is the Windows shortcut for switching between windows, so that doesn't work for me. I tried setting the `Indent selection` hotkey to `<none>` instead of `Tab`, but the issue seems to persist (pressing tab inserts tabs at the beginning of the line, not the cursor). By the way, I don't mean anything strange by "inserting `\t`" - I just want the `Tab` key to do the same thing in TexStudio as in Notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be related to a bug in version 2.8.4.

> tab is assigned to indentSelection, unfortunately the operation can't be left without a shortcut due to a bug (fixed in repository)

From the relevant [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1095/). Jan Sundermeyer says the bug will be fixed in the next version.